# Logging information appearing in Response

Tags: apache, symfony, http-headers

I am calling json api built using Symfony2 using LAMP stack.

URL for api is like 
http://ab.ab.com/new/358342/17/12.948468/77.718571

Response I get back correctly:
{"Result":{"statusCode":1,"statusMsg":"Created Successfully"}}

However http headers contain the information I am logging in server. Example is

-wf-1-1-1-3:185|[{"Type":"INFO","File":"","Line":"","Label":"app"},"Data From Publisher Device Id:358342045834581 Route Id: 17 Lat:12.948468 Lng77.718571 Timestamp:2014-09-18 13:23:20 Data:tstsst|S-1"]|

Above logging info is coming back in Http header of response.

How should I disable the server logging info coming back.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out.
I was using firephp handler and firephp adds the logging information back in response through http headers.

firephp is useful tool for debugging json apis, however should be disabled in production to avoid revealing sensitive information.

I switched to fingers_crossed handler.